# How to make std::vector reuse a given memory block?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-management

A memory block holds values I'd like to use as an `std::vector`. I currently copy the values over using `std::memcpy`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    const std::size_t count = 2097152;
    float* ptr = (float*)std::malloc(count * sizeof(float)); // raw ptr for simplicity
    // ...
    std::vector<float> vec(count, 0);
    std::memcpy(vec.data(), ptr, count * sizeof(float));
    //...
    std::free(ptr);
}
```

However the copying is unnecessary, since `ptr` is no longer needed at this point. How can I make `std::vector` reuse the memory and take normal ownership of it?

Comment: [Read up on allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)

Comment: FWIW: If you need to pass a pointer to a legacy function to have the data populated you can just use `std::vector<float> info(some_size); legacy_function(info.data());` and now the vector has the information in it.